# Graphical Ping Plotter, similar to Perfgraph?

Tags: software-recommendation, network, ping, graph, macos

On Windows, I use a program called [Perfgraph](http://codefromthe70s.org/perfgraph3.aspx), which, among other things, showed a visual graph of ping latency to various hosts in my Task bar. Here's an example:

[image: Perfgraph 3.0 from CodeFromThe70s.org]

The ping metric is the graph on the far right.

Does anyone know if something like this is available for OS X? I use it to ping my router and my DNS name server so that I always have a graphical indicator on my connection quality, and if there are problems I know if the source is inside or outside my router.

So far, the only "alternative" is the CLI `ping` command, which just doesn't present the information in as easily digestible format as Perfgraph.

I don't need all the other functions of Perfgraph, I just want that ping plotter!

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

I have a nice CLI solution - it's called [mtr](https://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/). It's installable via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [ports](https://www.macports.org/).

Here is a screenshot:

[image: text interface mtr]

Comment: Thanks, though not as graphical/colorful as I'm looking for. It really helps when you can see at a glance when something is above normal range just by seeing graph spikes, or color coding. Try to determine variation in a list of black on white numbers is (for me) not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`Nagios` does install with ports on MacOS X.

Have a look at these [performance graphs](http://www.nagios.com/products/nagiosxi/screenshots).

[image]

I must quote here the final message of Nagions installer:

> But Nagios is a complex program so you should read the documentation online at
>   http://www.nagios.org or locally at /opt/share/nagios/docs/index.html to fully understand Nagios.

Comment: thanks daniel, i will take a look at this. i've been interested in playing with nagios for a while now.

Comment: → Ian, I also started testing `SmokePing`:
http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/
and I'll add this answer if it's as rock solid as other tools from Tobias.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote small app called [Lagometer](https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/lagometer/id425509486?mt=12) which shows ping to selected host (you can set it in preferences) as a graph in menubar. It works only with one host, but should work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Some time ago I actually tried that, but at the time it just showed a colored dot icon. Looks better now. :)